# Divide by zero with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query works fine for each and every test case if you choose the person's last name:

```
SELECT P.Patient_ID, P.Person_FirstName, P.Person_LastName
    , H.Height
    , W.Weight
    , CASE
        when  H.Height is not null then W.Weight / (H.Height * H.Height)
        else null
     END as BMI
FROM 
    VIEW_BillPatient P
    LEFT JOIN H on P.Patient_ID = H.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN W on P.Patient_ID = W.Patient_ID  

WHERE   
    P.Person_LastName = 'ZZtest'
```

This even works when H.Height is `null` or W.Weight is `null`.

Unfortunately, as soon as I take the `WHERE` clause off and try to run it for everybody, I get a divide by zero error.

```
SELECT P.Patient_ID, P.Person_FirstName, P.Person_LastName
    , H.Height
    , W.Weight
    , CASE
        when  H.Height is not null then W.Weight / (H.Height * H.Height)
        else null
     END as BMI
FROM 
    VIEW_BillPatient P
    LEFT JOIN H on P.Patient_ID = H.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN W on P.Patient_ID = W.Patient_ID
```

Error:

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

(Sub-queries H and W respectively return a Patient_ID and the last value for Height or Weight in the database, as usually there is more than one recorded (or null if none is found).  The formula is to calculate Body Mass Index as seen in the code)

What am I doing wrong?  (MS SQL SERVER 2008-R2)

Comment: Most likely, you've got one or more records in H whose Height field is 0. Those should be found and fixed, or, if 0 is a valid value for that field, add a clause to your CASE which accounts for it.

Comment: No, individually the Height can be null as well.

Comment: So, did any of these answers warrant acceptance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
SELECT P.Patient_ID, P.Person_FirstName, P.Person_LastName
    , H.Height
    , W.Weight
    , CASE
        when  H.Height != 0 then W.Weight / (H.Height * H.Height)
        else null
     END as BMI
FROM 
    VIEW_BillPatient P
    LEFT JOIN H on P.Patient_ID = H.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN W on P.Patient_ID = W.Patient_ID
```

NULL != 0 is already false, so you'll get null in that case, but you'll also get null for 0.

Comment: Oh, and in the unlikely case that you have ansi null behavior turned off, then change the when line to:
    when COALESCE(H.Height, 0) != 0 then W.Weight / (H.Height * H.Height)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `nullif(expr1,expr2)`.

> Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.

In this case, `BMI` will be `null` if `height` is `0` or `null` or if `weight` is `null`

```
SELECT P.Patient_ID, P.Person_FirstName, P.Person_LastName
    , H.Height
    , W.Weight
    , W.Weight / nullif(H.Height * H.Height, 0) as BMI
FROM 
    VIEW_BillPatient P
    LEFT JOIN H on P.Patient_ID = H.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN W on P.Patient_ID = W.Patient_ID  

WHERE   
    P.Person_LastName = 'ZZtest
```

... or simply change your case condition to explicitly avoid `0`. You'll get `null` if `height` is `0` or `null` or if `weight` is `null`

```
SELECT P.Patient_ID, P.Person_FirstName, P.Person_LastName
    , H.Height
    , W.Weight
    , case when H.Height != 0 then W.Weight / (H.Height * H.Height) end as BMI
FROM 
    VIEW_BillPatient P
    LEFT JOIN H on P.Patient_ID = H.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN W on P.Patient_ID = W.Patient_ID  

WHERE   
    P.Person_LastName = 'ZZtest
```

Comment: Wouldn't `nullif(H.Height * H.Height, 0)` still give a `divide by zero` error when H.Height is 0 or if H.Height is null?

Comment: @NathanKoop No, you'll get `null`. Don't believe me? Try `select 1 / nullif(0 * 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with NULL values, it's with a zero.

If you try and do math on a `NULL`, it will return a `NULL`.

Instead you need to filter out the H.Height's with a zero value

```
WHEN H.Height>0 THEN ...
```